# Where do I remove null elements in a forEach-loop/function?

Tags: javascript

If my data looks like `[Object, null, Object, Object]` and I'm using the function shown below, I would like to remove the null element of the array. Right now I try to ignore all null elements by using `if (item) {}`.
But I want to remove this element completly, to get `[Object, Object, Object]`

```
function addId(obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).indexOf('Array') >= 0) {
        obj.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item) {
                item.id = item.id || Random.id();
                addId(item);
            }
        });
    }
    else if (typeof obj == 'object') {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            addId(obj[key]);
        });
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: **Note:** `if(item)` will also not allow `0`, `""`(empty string), `undefined`, `false`. This will not only prevent `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the `null` element.

```
arr.filter(function(item){ return item !== null }).forEach(function(item) {
    item.id = item.id || Random.id();
    addId(item);
});
```

Or even simpler, `obj.filter(function(item){ return item })`, though it will basically just filter out all *falsey* elements including `null`.

Comment: @Tushar ah I assumed that when OP was doing `forEach` and since the callback is being called, since he said he was already using `if(item)`, it must be an array.

Comment: clarified it @Tushar

Comment: My problem with that is, that the filter works as there won't be an id added to the element if it is null. But what I need is, that the null-element should be removed. If I'm writing the result of the function to the console, I still see the null elements in the arrays...

Answer (score 3):

try this - simple and elegant

```
newarr = arr.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return !(item === null)
})
```

Comment: that is just a returned array name.Any ways i edited it to a meaning full name .Thankyou @Tushar

Comment: Why `!( === )` and not `!==` operators. You can save one operation

Answer (score 0):

You should try this simple solution using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove `null` values:

```
var array = [1, null, 3, null];
array = array.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 

array // [1, 3]
```